# HOW to keep dialogue box open after pressing button (android)

Tags: android

I want to keep dialogue box open, after button is clicked.I have set cancelable property false..but its not working (ANDROID).Please guide me?? psudocode  is there

```
 Builder ad= new (Dialogue .....)
ad.setCancelable(false);
ad.setPositivebutton("ok",....){ 
onclicklistner(){ }

ad.setNegativebytton("SpeekAgain",...)

onclicklistner{
} ad.show();
```

Dialogue closes on both buttons..i  want it should keep open on one button

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872164/andengine-ask-questions-with-toast/16872284#16872284

Comment: can you please post the actual code

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the dialogs `OnShow` and then whatever button you want to override

```
d.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener(){

        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button b = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                    //handle click
                }
            });
        }

    });
```